# Thread synchronization when using BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, mqtt

I am trying to process some messages that I get from an MQ infrastructure.I have two blocking queues,`sharedQueue` and `pubQueue`. The `sharedqueue` gets filled up with the messages that I get from the MQ infrastructure as below.It will put the messages to `sharedQueue`.

> client.setCallback(new CallBack("inst", sharedQueue));

The messagemanipulator thread will read from the `sharedQueue` , process it and put the response to `pubQueue` for later publishing.

> new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue,pubQueue).run();

The publisher thread will take messages from `pubQueue` and publish it to the MQ infrastructure.

> new PublisherThread(pubQueue).run();

Below is the full code :

```
 public class ArrayBlockingQueueExample {

 private BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(64);
 private BlockingQueue<String> pubQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(64);


public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttException, Exception {

    new ArrayBlockingQueueExample().startThreads();

}

public void startThreads() throws MqttException, Exception{

    MqttClient client =  new MQTTClientFactory().getInstance();
    client.setCallback(new CallBack("inst", sharedQueue));

    new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue,pubQueue).run();
    new PublisherThread(pubQueue).run();


}



 public MessageManipulatorThread( BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue , BlockingQueue<String> pubQueue){

    this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    this.pubQueue = pubQueue;

}

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String msg = sharedQueue.take();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "manipulator runnning => "+msg);
                pubQueue.put(msg);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


 }

public class PublisherThread implements Runnable {

private BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue;

public PublisherThread(BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue){

    this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;

}

     public void run() {
         while (true) {
             System.out.println("Running pub");
             try {
                 System.out.println("pub=>"+sharedQueue.take() );
                 Thread.sleep(500);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }

  }
```

The problem is `new PublisherThread(pubQueue).run();` never works.I am guessing this is a thread synchronization issue.The `pubQueue` is supposed to wait till it has any data filled up by the `MessageManipulatorThread`, but it doesnt look like that.The `PublisherThread` is waiting upon the `pubQueue` to be free, but it never becomes free ! , is there anything else I should do for this ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: WHy don't you use an `ExecutorService` instead of doing its job by hand?

Comment: Can use , but this is relatively simple requirement,thats why.

Comment: @fge When you only need two threads, there's no sense in adding overhead of an `ExecutorService`. Unless he wants to process messages from the `pubQueue` asynchronously, he doesn't need an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `Runnable.run()` instead of `Thread.start()`, so this:

```
new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue,pubQueue).run();
new PublisherThread(pubQueue).run();
```

Won't work. That's because `run()` actually runs the method of the runnable inside the current thread instead of creating a new thread and executing it separately.

Instead, do this:

```
new Thread(new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue,pubQueue), "MessageManipulatorThread").start();
new Thread(new PublisherThread(pubQueue), "PublisherThread").start();
```

**Edit:**

fge made the following comment in the question:

> Why don't you use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of doing its job by hand?

To clarify what he means, he means using an `ExecutorService` to process the messages for the `pubQueue` instead of creating a thread to pull the messages and processing them manually. That code would look like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
new Thread(new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue, executor), "MessageManipulatorThread").start();
```

Then the `MessageManipulatorThread` class would change to:

```
public class MessageManipulatorThread implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue;
    private ExecutorService executor;

    public MessageManipulatorThread(BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue, ExecutorService executor){
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String msg = sharedQueue.take();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "manipulator runnning => "+msg);
                executor.execute(new PublisherThread(msg));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then change `PublisherThread` so that it uses processes only the single message that gets passed to it. This is another approach to what you're trying to do.

This approach also allows some flexibility. Using the other approach, `PublisherThread` can only process one message at a time (synchronous). Using the `ExecutorService` interface allows you to change the implementation, which can allow it to process more than one message at a time (asynchronous) simply by changing this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

To this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

That statement allows the executor to start up to 10 threads, which means up to 10 messages can be processed at once. See the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class for more ways of creating `ExecutorService` implementations.

Comment: +1 but his "threads" are actually `Runnable`s.  He needs to do `new Thread(new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue,pubQueue)).start()`

Comment: Also `run()` doesn't "block the current thread".  It runs the method in the current thread.  Just to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are your problem:

```
new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue,pubQueue).run();
new PublisherThread(pubQueue).run();
```

You should first have your "Thread" classes extend `Thread` instead of just implementing `Runnable`, then call this instead:

```
new MessageManipulatorThread(sharedQueue,pubQueue).start();
new PublisherThread(pubQueue).start();
```

As written, your code doesn't actually spawn any new threads, so the first `run()` method never returns and your second `run()` method never gets called.